# How to use setSupportActionBar(toolbar) in Adapter?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-adapter

1. setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
2. ((Activity)context).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

I tried many times in different ways but it shows an error.

Anyone, please suggest to me an idea to use it in the adapter.

Comment: Why do you want this in the adapter? why can not you update in activity?

Comment: because I am not using Activity and I want to set it through Adapter in Layout.

Comment: You should have either Activity/Fragment to hold your adapter right?

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer:

((AppCompatActivity) context).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

before it, I was using it like this. but it didn't work for me.

1.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
2. ((Activity)context).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Answer (score 0):

pass the activity context in your adapter.

```
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(activity);
```

Adapter Class::

```
Context context;
public Adapter(Context c){
      this.context = c;
}
```

Now use context to set ActionBar like:

```
(Activity) context.getSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```